# ASP MVC cannot override bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tried so much to override bootstrap css with the following navbar css. Every time I try to load the css, I can't even see anything in my browser

```
 .navbar-default {
    background-color: #205ba2;
    border-color: #2d74ca;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #dce9f8;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #dce9f8;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #dce9f8;
    background-color: #2d74ca;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: #dce9f8;
    background-color: #2d74ca;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #2d74ca;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #2d74ca;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
    color: #ecf0f1;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
    color: #dce9f8;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: #ecf0f1;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: #dce9f8;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
        color: #dce9f8;
        background-color: #2d74ca;
    }
}
```

[image]

This is the correct order in my opinion but it doesnt work at any time.

Comment: 1) Probably you import yours first then bootstrap itself so your values get overridden (assumption).
2) you should really avoid doing it like this, overriding color variables and such like you do is a maintenance hell, you should use bootstrap's less files instead and set other values to the variables instead of recreating every rule with new values. 3) if 1) is incorrect, maybe you are having cache problems, try erasing the browser cache.

Comment: Can you show your html too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to include your CSS link to the page after link to
   Bootstrap. For example:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="mytheme.css">
   ```
2. For some rules you need to use [!important](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).
3. Also try to add any query string to your CSS-file URL to avoid
   сaching problem, for example:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="mytheme.css?version=new">
   ```